# Can I change the django rate limiter timeout?

Tags: python, django, api

I'm building an API in Python and Django and have encountered the rate limits set by django.
 Now, I've adjusted the rate limits for users and anons accordingly but I was wondering if there was a way to change or reduce the time in the following error response.

```
{
    "detail": "Request was throttled. Expected available in 7735 seconds."
}
```

Specifically I would like to reduce the **7735** seconds. 
Also, if I'm not mistaken, the timer counts down from 86400 seconds i.e. 1 day ?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can by installing an external plugin for that like django-ratelimit**